# What's the best way to sell my iPhone 3G in the UK?

Tags: iphone

The same as this question ( http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-sell-my-iphone-3gs ) except with the UK in mind.

I have a 16GB iPhone 3G and have recently upgraded (we don't need to argue if it's an upgrade :p) to the iPhone 4. What's the recommended way to sell it in the UK? It has one small crack on the back near the vibration switch so it probably doesn't count as near new (depending on your definition of near).

Answer (score 4):

The lowest hassle way is probably via one of these "phone recycling" sites.  eg:

- [Mazuma Mobile](http://www.mazumamobile.com/sell_mobile_phone.php?action=view&prod=1192) (offering £172 or £189.20 in Argos
  vouchers currently)
- [Envirophone](http://www.envirofone.com/Apple/iPhone+3G+16GB/details.aspx) (offering £160 currently)
- [FoneBank](http://www.fonebank.com/recycle_sell_mobile_phone_Apple%20iphone_3G%2016GB.aspx) (offering £161 currently)

It might not be the best deal on offer, but it's easy.  I sold an old (though much cheaper) handset via Mazuma recently with no problems.

Comment: O2 will also take it back: http://www.o2recycle.co.uk/

Answer (score 2):

I sold mine on eBay and it was quite a hassle. Before I managed the final sale the iPhone was won twice by bogus bidders.

And not only do you have to pay eBay fees (listing + 10% of final sale price)  but you'll probably have to pay paypal fees as well. After these fees I made about £190. Caveat venditor.

If you can get similar from one of the recyclers then I'd recommend. I've used both Mazuma and Envirofone before with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

[AV Forums](http://www.avforums.com/forums/iphone-classified-adverts/) has a well established buying and selling forum. You'll get a far better price than a recycling site would offer.